# Add exclude to existing yum repo configuration with puppet

Tags: centos, puppet, yum

I'm using puppet for managing configuration a bunch of CentOS 5 servers. I would like to add a some package exclusions to the CentOS base yum repo configuration. Is there a way to do this with puppet?

I am going to use the remi repo version of some packages and want to exclude the base versions from yum. To enable remi I have a `yumrepo` resource defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exclude` parameter in `yumrepo`

```
yumrepo { 'centos_base' :
    baseurl => "...",
    enabled => 1,
    priority => 1,
    exclude => "package-name",
}
```

You can also require a particular `yumrepo` when installing a package.

```
package { "package-name" :
  ensure => installed,
  require => Yumrepo["RemiRepo"],
}
```

Comment: I also included the `descr` and `name` yumrepo parameters and this seems to work. Thanks!